# ASP.NET SQL Server report writer that will work under medium trust

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I am looking for recommendations on a reporting alternative that I can use in my ASP.NET applications, against a SQL Server 2008 database, that will run under a "Medium Trust" security option.

I have all my clients hosted under my Rackspace/Mosso cloud solution, and have run into this stumbling block. I'd hate to have to go back to a dedicated server (at 3X the cost), so is there any other (free or low cost) reporting option that would work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Stimulsoft](http://stimulsoft.com/) if you'd like a low-cost reporting tool.  It will work under medium trust and they offer very responsive support.